# Is there an interval that contains more squares of primes than primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The primes $p$ are, of course, in one-to-one correspondence with the squares of primes $p^2$. But is there any interval $a < x < b$ possible where the primes thin out so much, that it contains more squares of primes than primes?

Comment: Trivially, yes. Any interval where $a = p^2-1$ and $b = p^2+1$, for some prime $p$.

Comment: @Ross: Maybe you can make it less easy by requiring that the interval contains $n$ primes with $n>>0$.

Comment: How embarrassing. Oh well.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Having been spanked on the simpleminded phrasing of the question I'm hesitant to try again.

Comment: I'd be interested to know the motivation for this question.

Comment: @Josh Chen: I had just learned about Skewes' number. If the primes get thin enough that the prime-counting function falls under the logarithmic integral, maybe they get *really* thin, and stay that way for a huge interval. Then there could be an interval where the squares of much smaller primes fall into the spot where there are no primes themselves.

Comment: But in fact the trival case from @LarsH is just a degenerate solution of exactly what I was imagining.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to "spank." I probably should have said, "Maybe there were additional constraints that you meant to describe?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interval $23 \lt x \lt 29$ is one such

Comment: And $47<x<53$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think the intent of your question was that the number of primes in the interval, call it $\pi(n)'$, is ***non-zero***. If so, then the simplest case is,

$$p_n^2\leq x \leq p_{n+1}^2$$

for prime $p_i$. Your question then assumes the count as $\pi(n)'<2.$ However,

1. A consequence of *[Legendre's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture)* is that the number of primes in that interval is ***at least 2***.
2. More strongly, if *[Brocard's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_conjecture)* is true then, for $n>1$, there are ***at least 4***.

As the count $\pi(n)' =2, 5, 6, 15, 9, 22, 11, 27, 47,\dots$ ([A050216](http://oeis.org/A050216)) goes up fast, it is highly doubtful that Brocard's conjecture is false.

Comment: I believe [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) would also be relevant.

Comment: No, in fact when I asked my question, I was imagining a desert containing *no* primes, not even one, but where at least two prime squares fall. You're saying that Legendre's conjecture makes that impossible.

Comment: And (after reading it) I see Bertrand's postulate, which is proven, completely rules out my scenario.

Comment: @RossPresser: Yes, Legendre's (and Brocard's) conjecture make it impossible since they postulate at least $2$ and $4$ primes, respectively, in that interval.

Comment: Those two are conjectures, but Bertrand's postulate is proven.